# Special characters escaping with JS and PHP

Tags: php, javascript, encoding

my application geting Text from a input field an post it over ajax to a php file for saving it to db.

```
var title = encodeURIComponent($('#title').val());
```

if I escape() the title it is all OK but i have Problems with "+" character. So i use the encodeURIComponent().

Now i habe a Problem with german special characters like "ö" "ä" "ü" they will be displayed like a crypdet something....

Have some an idea how can i solve this problem?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose this has to do with encoding : your HTML page might be using UTF-8, and the special characters are encoded like this :

```
>>> encodeURIComponent('ö');
"%C3%B6"
```

When your PHP page receives this, it has to know it's UTF-8, and deal with it as UTF-8 -- which means that everything on the server-side has to work with UTF-8 :

- PHP code must use functions that can work with multi-byte characters
- The database (db, tables, columns, ...) must use UTF-8 for storing data
- When generating HTML pages, you need to indicate it's UTF-8 too, ...

For instance, if you are using `var_dump()` on the PHP side to display what's been sent from the client, don't forget to indicate that the generated page is in UTF-8, with something like this :

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

Else, the browser will use it's default charset -- which is not necessarily *the right one*, and possibly display garbage.

Comment: DB and HTML works with uft-8, how can i decode %C3%B6 in normal characters?

Comment: As you see %C3%B6 = ¶Á there 2 characters, %c3 and %b6 ... that is the problem

Comment: Actually, `%C3%B6` doesn't mean two characters ; it means two bytes, but the way those two bytes are interpreted depend on the charset ;;; If you are working with UTF-8, which is a multi-byte charset *(each character can take up to 4 bytes)*, those two bytes actually represent only 1 character ;-) ;;; if you make sure everything is interpreted as UTF-8, you'll be fine ;-)

Comment: How can i say the php "this is a uft8 string"? 

The Db works with utf8_bin

Answer (score 0):

You might use `escape("AbcÄüö")` and you would get "Abc%C4%FC%F6"

In php you could then use `urldecode($myValue)` to get "AbcÄüö" again

Comment: If you escape you will get problems with "+" character

Comment: What do you mean by problems?